# Bidirectional dependencies between classes causing issues

Tags: python-3.x, circular-dependency

I have a class to represent a resource (for the sake of the example, let's say a folder), and a factory class to create those resources. 
The issue is that, for clarity purposes, I wish to provide each folder with it's own factory, allowing it to generate it's sub-folders.

This currently looks like this :

*folder.py*

```
import FolderFactory

class Folder
   def __init__(self):
       self.file_factory = FolderFactory(self)
       self.sub_folders = []
```

*folder_factory.py*

```
import File

class FolderFactory
   def __init__(self, folder):
       assert isinstance(folder, Folder)
       self.folder = Folder(folder)

   def create_sub_folder(name):
       // Create Folder
       self.folder.sub_folders.append(new_folder)
```

But obviously this generate a circular reference, which cause an error.
Is there an issue with my design, or is there a way to implement this cleanly ?

The end goal would be to be able to write something along the lines of

```
folder.folder_factory.create_folder("new")
```

Please note that the actual factory class I'm working with have a large amount of functions to generate different resources in the parent resource, which explains the need to separate the object definition and the management functions.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read !

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `self` from the `FolderFactory` to the constructor of the folder, to be used as a reference to its 'parent'.

```py
import FolderFactory

class Folder
   def __init__(self, factory):
       self.file_factory = FolderFactory(self)
       self.folder_factory = factory
       self.sub_folders = []
```

```py
import File

class FolderFactory
   def __init__(self, folder):
       assert isinstance(folder, Folder)
       self.folder = Folder(folder, self)

   def create_sub_folder(name):
       // Create Folder
       self.folder.sub_folders.append(new_folder)
```

Comment: But the circular dependency is still present ?